# WOL on mythtv box

Tags: networking, ubuntu, hardware, lan, wake-on-lan

I am trying to make WOL working on my MythTV box but I am doing something completely wrong as I cannot get the box to turn on.

I am running Mythbuntu 12.04. The MB is ASUS P8H61-I LX R2.0 which supports WOL as to my knowledge.

When I run `ethtool eth0` via terminal I get this:

```
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
```

So I know the network card supports WOL as well.

When I turn the box off and then tries to send a magic packet, nothing happens at all. So either I have a wrong setup on the box or I am sending the packet the wrong way.

My router is the Netgear CG3000, but I am unsure what I have to setup in that to make it work if anything is needed to set up.

The box's local IP is 192.168.0.11

Is there a setup or something that I am missing somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a NIC issue with the motherboard